# Getting Table border-collapse:collapse to work with StringBuilder sent to Gmail

Tags: c#, html, css, gmail

I am trying to create an e-mail in a .Net/C# program, which includes inserting a TABLE object using the border-collapse:collapse option using Stringbuilder.  This will be read with Gmail.  I have read where "styles" have to be put in the HEAD section when using Gmail.  I have tried a bunch of different combinations that don't seem to make any difference.  Below code **will** create the table, but it creates borders around everything, which is why I want the border-collapse option.  I'm not worried at this point about putting this CSS in a file until I can get it working this way. Thanks!

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>");
sb.Append("<head style=\"border-collapse:collapse\">");
sb.Append("<title>");
sb.Append("Page-");
sb.Append(Guid.NewGuid());
sb.Append("</title>");
sb.Append("</head>");

sb.Append("<body>");
sb.Append("<table border=\"1\">");
sb.AppendFormat("<tr><td>Color1:</td><td>{0}</td></tr>", "Red");
sb.AppendFormat("<tr><td>Color2:</td><td>{0}</td></tr>", "Yellow");
sb.AppendFormat("<tr><td>Color3:</td><td>{0}</td></tr>", "Blue");
sb.AppendFormat("<tr><td>Color4:</td><td>{0}</td></tr>", "Green");
sb.Append("</table>");
sb.AppendLine("</body>");
sb.AppendLine("</html>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `style` on your table tag and define custom properties on this.

E.g.: `<table style="border-collapse:collapse;">`

Comment: I changed the head tag to be just: <head>.  Then I tried this:  sb.Append("<table style=\"border-collapse:collapse; border=\"1\"\">");    And no borders at all are showing up.  I think this is because of Gmail ignorning styles that aren't in the head section.

Comment: @Craig can you post the HTML that the Gmail had renderized? I think there is a "see original message" somewhere on the gmail client.

Comment: <html xmlns=3D'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><title>Page-70c3c75a-bc6=
2-436a-8791-b47c81259229</title></style></head><body><table style=3D"border=
-collapse:collapse; border=3D"1""><tr><td>Color1:</td><td>Red</td></tr><tr>=
<td>Color2:</td><td>Yellow</td></tr><tr><td>Color3:</td><td>Blue</td></tr><=
tr><td>Color4:</td><td>Green</td></tr></table></body>
</html>